# Does the following series converge or not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{n+\cos(n)}{n^2+n\log(n)+10\sin(n)}$$
I cannot think of any of my textbook methods to work with.

Comment: It's the same as $\frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges

Comment: if you wanna be rigorous, just note $n+\cos(n) \ge \frac{n}{2}$ for $n$ large, and $n^2+n\log n + 10\sin(n) \le 2n^2$ for $n$ large.

Comment: How do we prove that?

Comment: not a proof, but if you replace the $\infty$ with an $x$ and plug the new series into desmos, you'll see if it converges or not

Comment: @MPapas for the first, you want to show $n \ge -2\cos(n)$ for $n$ large. But $-2\cos(n) \le 2$, which is $\le n$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Yeah check this out: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qta053ybur

Comment: How do we show the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for sufficiently large $n$ we have $$n+\cos n\ge {n\over 2}$$and $$n^2+n\log n+10\sin n\le 3n^2$$therefore$${n+\cos n\over n^2+n\log n+10\sin n}\ge{1\over 6n}$$which means that **the series diverges.**

Comment: the second centered inequality is false

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it........

Comment: how do we show the 2nd one?

Comment: I changed the $2$nd condition to make it a little easier. Note that $$n\log n\le n^2\\n^2\le n^2\\10\sin n\le n^2$$for $n>4$.

Answer (score 0):

It is just n/n^2 which diverges because you can take out all terms that are not n or n^2 because they are the greatest terms in the fraction as n approaches infinity. 1/n is the simplification and it diverges.

Comment: why is it like that?

Comment: You can take out all terms because that is an already proven textbook method. It is just like that because somebody already proved(though I figured it out myself). I don't know of a formal proof for that fact, but it is the intuition that you should study on.